# Element ID of object in Powershell array

Tags: arrays, powershell, element

I have an array of objects, a list of computers, so the array looks something like this:

```
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| size(MB) | Computer  |   Location    |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 100      | compname1 | C:\Users\etc\ |
| Offline  | compname2 | Offline       |
| 30       | compname3 | C:\users\etc2 |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
```

I need to iterate through these and any that are offline, scan them again. The issue I have is that on each iteration of the loop, how do I find the element number of the current object in the array?

I had:

```
$element = [array]::IndexOf($complist.computer,$compname)
```

Which did return a value but doesn't seem to be correct (the returned element does not match the correct array element).

The end game is that I need to run through the array for the computers marked as 'Offline', run the scan on that computer and then replace the element in the array with the new data.

Comment: I ended up changing the logic in the script and just incrementing through all elements with $i++ and using that number as the element ID.  Would be nice to have a n answer to the question though.

Comment: I would probably go about it differently in PowerShell. What you really want to do is to keep the 'online' computers in the list and replace the data on the 'offline' computers in the list. Instead of changing the existing array, I'd probably do something similar to: `$data | Foreach { if ($_.Location -eq "Offline") { Write-Output (Get-ComputerDetails -ComputerName $_.Computer) } else { Write-Output $_ } }`

Comment: The problem is that it's not a 1:1 replacment. For example, a PC will have one record if it's offline. When it gets scanned however it may have multiple users so it may have 1, 2 ,3 .... records in the CSV.  The reason it has to be CSV is to be human readable when I send it out.

Comment: That's not a problem either. In that case, the scriptblock handling the `Foreach` could just do `Write-Output` multiple times and you'll get more entries in the output than you had in the input. Let me know if you want me to write up an answer with a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
$newarray =
foreach ($item in $array)
 {
   if (
        ( $item.location -eq 'offline' ) -and 
        ( Test-Connection $Item.computer -Quiet )
       )

       { 
         Write-Verbose "Found $($item.Computer) online.  Updating."
         foreach ($userdir in (Get-ChildItem "\\$($item.Computer)\C$\users" -Directory))
          {
            $DirSize = (Get-ChildItem $userdir -Recurse | measure -Sum length).sum
            [PSCustomobject]@{
                               Size = $DirSize
                               Computer = $item.Computer
                               Location = 'C:\users\' + $userdir.Name
                             }
          }
        }
      Else { $item }
   }
```

Since it's not a 1:1 replacement, you can't just do a replace - you're going to have to create a new array.  This reads in the original array, and creates new entries for computers that were offline but are now online.  Everything else just passes through.